# How to insert data from 2 different sources into 2 different tables in SQL server using Web application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, web-applications

Ok, basically i have created Web application in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and one page has this design:

[image: screenshot]

I have also created 3 tables in database :

products:
[`id`]
[`name`]

auctions:
[`id`]
[`productid`]
[`lastbider`]
[`bidvalue`]
[`lastbid`]

users:
[`id`]
[`name`]
[`password`]
[`bids`]

The thing i need is when i click on button it needs to insert text from `Textbox` into [`name`] from products table and also insert number from `Listbox` into [`bidvalue`] from auctions table. How do i do this, do i need 2 `SqlCommands`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, basically you are trying to perform `INSERT` into two different tables and so you need to perform two different `INSERT` operations. Though, I suspect you probably want to perform an `UPDATE` instead but can't say for sure unless you clarify it.

Again, you can perform both the operation in single shot using a stored procedure like

```
create procedure usp_addData(@name varchar(10), @bidvalue INT)
as
begin
//Perform first insert/update in products table using the @name parameter

//perform second insert/update in auctions table using the @bidvalue parameter
end
```

Call this stored procedure from your application instead of making two different DB calls.

*** Omitted `C#` code samples to keep the answer simple. You can get many example of calling stored procedure from `C#` in SO.

Comment: No, i do need `INSERT` operation since i am adding new items into `auctions` table. The existing ones will be updated on another page, but that's another story. Thank you though, a procedure solves this the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and just call

```
    InsertData("Insert into Products (Name) Values ('" + txtName.Text + "'); Insert Into Auctions (bidvalue) Values ('" + lstBidValues.SelectedValue + "');"); 

    public void InsertData(string query)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection string here"))
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you will need the `ProductId` in your Auctions table, you will need to do an insert in Products and then get the `productId` you created in your sql to add it to your Auctions table together with the `bidValue` that you have. This can be done with one `SqlCommand` that calls your stored procedure which should look like below...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES('PRODUCT NAME')
    DECLARE @newProductId int = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO AUCTIONS(ProductId, lastBidder, bidValue, lastbid)
    VALUES (@newProductId, 'yourlastbidder, 'bidValue', 'lastbid')

END TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about that. I would like to add few changes to code. It should be `COMMIT` instead of `END` when we are talking about transactions. Whole code should look something like this :
`BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @newProductId int;
INSERT INTO products (name) VALUES (@name);
SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.id = @newProductId;
SELECT @newProductId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO auctions (productid, bidvalue)
VALUES (@newProductId, @bidvalue);
COMMIT TRANSACTION`